# Allow specific local javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, content-security-policy

I'm using pinboard for all my bookmark storage, and they provide a little javascript bookmark for easy adding and tagging that I've got in my firefox toolbar. The beautified code:

```
javascript: q = location.href;
if (document.getSelection) {
    d = document.getSelection();
} else {
    d = '';
};
p = document.title;
void(open('https://pinboard.in/add?showtags=yes&url=' + encodeURIComponent(q) + '&description=' + encodeURIComponent(d) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(p), 'Pinboard', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=750,height=700'));
```

which works awesome for all http sites, but when I try to bookmark https sites I get this in the console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource: An attempt to execute inline scripts has been blocked.
```

I'm not sure if SO is the right SE-site for this, but I'm wondering how I might allow that specific script to execute everywhere. If I copy the javascript to the address field and run it manually everything works as it should.

Comment: Bad news: you can't. CSP is a jerk and will prevent you from using bookmarklets. Hopefully future versions of CSP fix that, but for now if a site has a CSP that forbids inline scripts, your only recourse is a fullfledged extension, rather than a bookmarklet. Google for "CSP bookmarklet" for a plethora of the CSP spec causing problems, like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, sorry to hear that. Post the comment as an answer and I'll accept it. It turns out that they do have an extension though so my problem is solved in a sort-of-roundabout way :)

Comment: it's kind of a time-sensitive answer - I don't know when CSP 2 "lands" but it could be next week or next month, and people finding this question'll just be confused if my comment was an actual answer =)

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I'll just let this wait then.